# Algorithm used to blur an image in html

Tags: html, algorithm, image-processing, blur

To blur an image "example.png" on a webpage, I am using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
img {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="example.png" alt="im" width="90" height="40">
</body>
</html>
```

- Is it possible to retrieve the blurred image ?
- Where can I find the algorithm used to blur the image or at least to know the method.

Comment: when you want to retrieve the image?

Comment: to analyze what filter (average, gaussian...) they are using and I need the pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the image cannot be retrieved since it is calculated by your browser. If you request (GET) the image, it will always be the original. Your best bet would be screenshotting it.

The algorithm used for `filter: blur` is called **Gaussian blur**.